# Selected item in listbox, to form part of a directory

Tags: vb.net, events, listbox, selecteditem, selectedindexchanged

I'm having a hard time trying to check if a file exist when the user selects an item from the listbox. 
The selected item is supposed to be converted into a part of a directory to open a file. I know for sure I have the right event and that the problem is within the "if" statement because without the "if" statement a message box will show the item name.
Its hard to explain in words so heres the code, and if someone finds an answer to this issue and I'm not on, Thanks.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim item As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
    If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\" & item & "\" & "config.yml") Then
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the If Statement and put the expression you use to create the file path into the Watch window to confirm it exists.

Comment: So you're saying that, with the `If` statement in place, `Button1` is not enabled?  If so then that means that the specified file does not exist.  If it did exist then the `If` condition would evaluate to `True` and `Button1` would be enabled.  Are you sure that `item` actually contains what you think it does?  Are the items in the `ListBox` actually `String` objects?  If you have used the `DisplayMember` then you actually want `Text` and not `SelectedItem`.  In fact, `Text` would be better regardless, if what you actually want is what's displayed in the selection.

Comment: By the way, you really should adjust that code.  Presumably you want to disable the `Button` when a new selection is made and the file does exist but you're never doing that.  I recommend that you import the `System.IO` namespace and then change the entire method body to `Button1.Enabled = File.Exists(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, ListBox1.Text, "config.yml"))`.  That will enable and disable as required.

Comment: it says:   (Application.StartupPath & "\" & item & "\" & "config.yml") "K:\MSE\MSE\bin\Debug\WorldEdit\config.yml" String

Comment: The code doesn't do what it wants. It does what you tell it to do. Looks like perfect code to me besides you need to add in first line `If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return `